# Connection between eth1 and wlan0 in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, bridge, ubuntu-16.04

I have 3 NICs as eth0, eth1 and wlan0. eth0 is connected to internet through router. DHCP server is running for eth1 and wlan0 for local network.
The clients on eth1 and wlan0 can access internet.
What I want to do is that the clients on eth1 and wlan0 communicate each other in local network. But they don't. 
Here is my configuration.

```
#loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WAN interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# LAN interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.100.1
  network 192.168.100.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0

  broadcast 192.168.100.255

# Wireless interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.200.1
  network 192.168.200.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.200.255
```

Please help me what I can do to make the connection between eth1 and wlan0.

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:81:98:36:1f:c1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.35  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::81:98ff:fe36:1fc1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7823 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2892002 (2.8 MB)  TX bytes:867774 (867.7 KB)
          Interrupt:42 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:30:20:6d:01:4b  
          inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::430:20ff:fe6d:14b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6003 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6040 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:864427 (864.4 KB)  TX bytes:2647145 (2.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:168850 (168.8 KB)  TX bytes:168850 (168.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:f7:10:46:db:b4  
          inet addr:192.168.200.1  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8ef7:10ff:fe46:dbb4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2740 (2.7 KB)
```

What I tried is to add rules like below.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score -1):

The cause was the firewall of Windows client.
I didn't even think that the firewall blocks even ping.

Comment: The clients under Ubuntu based DHCP server are Windows based PC. So I have tried the connection test between Win1(ethernet) and Win2(wifi). Sorry for that